# How do I calculate a point on a segmented line given a list of Vector3 and a distance?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to calculate a point in world spaaaaaace given a list of vectors and a distance from the starting point. I've done some searching and can't seem to find an answer to this question. How do I do it?

**EDIT**

[A gist of my implementation can be found on github.](https://gist.github.com/Herbstein/ab95dba03d2bf133ad60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of vectors V[0], V[1], ..., V[N-1], you should first compute the distances along the segmented line. D[0] = 0 and D[i] = D[i-1] + dist(V[i-1],V[i]) for i = 1, 2, ..., N-1.

Now when you want to compute the point at distance t along the segmented line, you first do a binary search to find i such that D[i-1] <= t < D[i], then you interpolate: V[i-1] + ((t - D[i-1]) / (D[i] - D[i-1])) * (V[i] - V[i-1]).

Comment: I can't say that this actually works, since I will have to change my implementation a little to accomodate this, but you will get the tick anyhow.

Comment: And this does indeed work. I had some trouble, but I accidentally flipped a boolean statement.